# Rails in production: JavaScript files not run

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, assets, production

I try to run rails application (Rails 4.2.0) in production mode with these settings:

*config/environment/production.rb*

```
require 'uglifier'

Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(output: {ascii_only: true, quote_keys: true})
  config.serve_static_files = true
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' 
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
end
```

*config/initializer/assets.rb*

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/* admin.*)
```

*app/assets/application.js*

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require select2
//= require init/select2
//= require lib/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min
//= require lib/moment.min
//= require lib/daterangepicker
//= require init/daterangepicker
//= require lib/bootstrap-notify
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
// lightgallery:
//= require lib/lightgallery/picturefill.min.js
//= require lib/lightgallery/lightgallery
//= require lib/jquery.mousewheel.min.js
//= require jquery.sortable
//= require photos
//= require_tree ./admin
//= require_tree .
```

*app/assets/photos.js*

```
// Loading photo for resources
(function($) {
  conslole.log('It is photos.js')
  // Check File API support
  if(window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader){
    var filesInput = document.getElementById('upload_photos');
    //...
  }

}());
```

I expect to see in browser console message 'It is photos.js', but it's absent.

I explored compiled file

*http://localhost:3000/assets/admin-a0144eae675b202d7e9a9fbca944636e6aa24fe7b0140b44ec68928303bc4717.js*

and found this piece of code in browser sources:

```
(function($) {
  console.log('It is photos.js')
  // Check File API support
  if(window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader){
    var filesInput = document.getElementById('upload_photos');
    //...
  }
}());
```

I can't understand why no message is shown in console.

But a lot of other js files and libs are working correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try `rake assets:precompile` in your app directory then push the new compiled files in production. I ran into the same problem with asset files not loading properly in production and this command did the trick for me.

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Of course I did it, but some js files don't apply to DOM.

Comment: You forgot a semicolon at the end of the line `conslole.log('It is photos.js')`